# Passing data from modal presentation

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to pass data to a "presentation modal" view and that data can be retrieved in `Detail`

**I need to pass the variable `title` to Detail ()**

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @State var showingDetail = false
    let title = "My Title"

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingDetail.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Detail")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
            Detail()
        }
    }
}


struct Detail: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                Text("Details view")
                Text("Details view")
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Booking", displayMode: .inline)

            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    print("close")
                }) { Image(systemName: "xmark")  }).accentColor(.pink)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a bit more code and information what data you want to pass into ModalView? Thanks

Comment: Post updates, you can check for more details. My variable is from an array but to make it simpler I have put `let title =" My title "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare it as a viariable/constant on Detail like this:

```
struct Detail: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    let title: String

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           ScrollView {
               VStack {
                   Text(title)
           //...end so on
```

and then pass it into the initialiser in ConotentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    //...

    }.sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
        Detail(title: self.title)
    }
    // ...
```